# Can one feed themselves?

Tags: grammaticality

I was helping my spouse to proof read some reports, shes a preschool teacher.

One sentence that seemed very strange to me was:

"... he fed him self confidently."

As far as I explain it to my self, is that one doesn't feed them selves?!

I suggested changing the sentence to:

"... he eats with confidence."

But my spouse pointed out that in her guidelines there is a point (quoted as is)

> feeding self confidence

Not really sure what that even means but she used that as a suggestion.

Comment: "feeding himself" is perfectly fine, but not "feeding him self". Just consider a sentence like: "The mother was happy when the child began feeding himself" or "The mother was happy when the child fed himself."

Comment: This is where a hyphen is required.  ***self-confidence, self-confidently***

Comment: @Silenus  Why "himself" ?  Why not "itself" or "themselves"?

Comment: @Centaurus, "itself" and "themselves" work too, just as well as "himself". I was just pointing out that "himself" works fine with the transitive verb "feed". I thought that was the OP's question.

Comment: Doesn't itself refer to nonhuman things? Themselves would be ok in 3rd person but we just writing about one person in simple past. No?

Comment: Yes, when a young child learns to feed himself/herself it is (after a brief period of dread due to the splattered food) a major milestone in childcare.

Comment: And when an adult is recovering from a serious illness, the ability to self-feed may again be a milestone.

Comment: I love this site :)

Comment: Children are sometimes referred to with the neuter "it", especially with the genitive form "its" (see wikipedia, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_(pronoun))

Comment: @ppumkin If I understand the context, there's a difference between "eating" and "feeding yourself." A child can eat but also not be able to feed himself, if he doesn't have the coordination to being a fork to his mouth, etc.

Comment: Silenus - Very interesting read about `it` - But we know the subject is male or female, since we writing a personalised report about that specific child, I wouldn't dare use "itself" as it may offend the parents :) As far as I understood from `... this usage has come to be considered too impersonal in the case of babies` is what I felt, when writing my comment. As far as neuter, using "it", is the only acceptable way of asking for the babies gender.

Comment: @Centaurus or indeed [*themself*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/themself) if you're using singular they.

Comment: It seems the term [*reflexive pronoun*](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/reflexive-pronouns) hasn't been mentioned so far .  It may be useful for further reading.  The British Council page I've linked has a nice clear explanation intended for learners of English.

Comment: Not that _feeding one's self-confidence_ (which you seem to mention at the end of your question) is something entirely different, which has little to do with actually putting food in one's mouth! Example: _Every exam he passed fed his self-confidence._

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, "him self" should clearly be "himself," but other than that, in the context of a report on a preschooler, "he fed himself confidently" is perfectly fine. A preschooler who feeds himself well is noteworthy.

Those were the days.

Comment: Yea I suppose in the context of a toddler, the actual actions of eating and feeding are skills that need to be learnt. As an adult it just sound wrong. I wouldn't say, "Yea man, I fed myself that Quarter Pounder"  Unless somebody was being sarcastic or a trying to exaggerate they stuffed their faces with the food. I think I get it now. Thanks

Comment: "Himself" is the most likely meaning, but if the teacher was talking about the toddler feeding the playgroup's pet gerbil, "he fed him self-confidently" would make sense.

Answer (score 6):

I feed myself. My wife feeds herself. I can feed her. She can feed me. I guess that at this point, and so far, I can and do feed myself with confidence (that I will get everything I want into my mouth without assistance). I am still reasonable neat and can keep most of the meal confined to me and my eating utensils. I hope to be able to continue for some time.

I suppose I could convince some unstable person to put a finger or two into their mouth and to try to eat his or her "self;" but, that would be unseemly and ungrammatical.

Comment: Thanks, this made the term itself clear to me - it's about "feeding yourself" in the sense of being able to eat on your own! That was somehow unclear to me first.